# undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass while collection is present

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im following Railscasts episode 111 (Advanced search) and it works in the back-end, but I can't figure out what Im doing wrong with displaying search results

```
<% @search.listings.each do |listing| %>
<%= render partial: "categories/listing-s" %>
<% end %>
```

I won't put all code her because it's quite straightforward. I have Listing model, Category model where from Listings are displayed and Search model for search manipulations. The search form is in the sidebar of each category

Let's say I want to filter Listings with price between 2000 and 2400.

```
Started POST "/searches" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-10-20 21:08:16 +0300
Processing by SearchesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ZoKN3mhgmk8ejJE8OKKo+yS7X1R5d7LRzGa9YaIuDVoahH0Fq8iMwclSMVZIej9YwI9i3/8ji+g65A8XRTVhtQ==", "search"=>{"keywords"=>"", "category_id"=>"", "min_price"=>"2000", "max_price"=>"2400"}, "button"=>""}
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "searches" ("keywords", "min_price", "max_price", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["keywords", ""], ["min_price", #<BigDecimal:7fbab61ebc98,'0.2E4',9(18)>], ["max_price", #<BigDecimal:7fbab61ebba8,'0.24E4',9(18)>], ["created_at", 2016-10-20 18:08:16 UTC], ["updated_at", 2016-10-20 18:08:16 UTC]]
   (2.3ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/searches/15
Completed 302 Found in 7ms (ActiveRecord: 3.0ms)
```

Ok, it's created and looks good to me. Then I have

```
Started GET "/searches/15" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-10-20 21:08:16 +0300
Processing by SearchesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"15"}
  Search Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "searches".* FROM "searches" WHERE "searches"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 15], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering searches/show.html.erb within layouts/application

  .....

  Listing Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "listings".* FROM "listings" WHERE (price >= '2000.0') AND (price <= '2400.0') ORDER BY created_at DESC
#<Listing:0x007fbab6bea6e0>
#<Listing:0x007fbab6bea500>
#<Listing:0x007fbab6bea3c0>
#<Listing:0x007fbab6bea190>
  Rendered searches/show.html.erb within layouts/application (81.0ms)
```

Last part of the log returns and collection of Listing models which is great. BUt why I still see **undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass** on <% @search.listings.each do |listing| %> ?

**Update with show action in searhes_controller**

```
def show
    @search = Search.find(params[:id])
end
```

MODEL

```
class Search < ApplicationRecord
    def listings
        @listings ||= find_listings
    end

    private

    def find_listings
        listings = Listing.order('created_at DESC')
        listings = listings.where("name like ?", "%#{keywords}%") if keywords.present?
        listings = listings.where(subcategory_id: category_id) if category_id.present?
        listings = listings.where("price >= ?", min_price.to_s) if min_price.present?
        listings = listings.where("price <= ?", max_price.to_s) if max_price.present?
        listings
        puts listings
    end


end
```

**Update 2 **

With the help of community I have figure out that I **shouldn't be using puts** in model because it return nil. Hope it will help you in case you have faced similar issue

Comment: show us your `show` action.

Comment: The listings for you search are `nil` I can tell you that much already. I might be able to tell you why when you post your controller code.

Comment: Updated the question with controller and model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing puts listing from the last line, as puts returns nil. so your `find_listings` method is returning nil instead of actual listings.

Comment: Really? Is it that simple? I didn't know that puts return nil. Thank you a lot, it helps and error has gone